# When does Ubuntu 22.04.2 come out?

Tags: upgrade, 22.04

I'm sorry if this is the wrong website to ask this question, but I'd like to know when Ubuntu 22.04.2 comes out (the second point release). I'd like to know because I'm currently on Ubuntu 20.04 and I'd like to do an in-place upgrade, but I don't want to risk having problems once upgraded. This machine is heavily relied on and it would not be okay if I ran into some problems after (or while) upgrading. Because of the fact that every point release has some fixes to the upgrade bridge, I'd like to wait until .2 comes out. When does that come out?

Comment: Some month(s) after 22.10 (in October) to allow time for bug fixing associated with that kernel version, so maybe half a year from now, maybe a bit sooner (than half a year from now). The Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS iso files are dated 2021-02-04, so I conclude that it was released during February.

Comment: If the machine is "heavily relied upon" then the solution is not to wait and hope for no problems. The solution is to test, test, test, and start that testing today. Test your hardware using a 22.04 LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment. Test your software by replicating your system in a Virtual Machine, and upgrading that test environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its now updated in official [ubuntu page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), where it is mentioned as **9th Febraury 2023** under futures section.

Answer (score 9):

Point Releases typically occur about 3-4 months after a normal 6-month release of Ubuntu.

Here's the 20.04 Release Cycle as an example:

```
Date      Kernel  Release
2020-04   5.4     20.04    Focal
2020-08   5.4     20.04.1  LTS-to-LTS upgrades enabled at .1

2020-10   5.8     20.10    Groovy
2021-02   5.8     20.04.2

2021-04   5.11    21.04    Hirsute
2021-08   5.11    20.04.3

2021-10   5.13    21.10    Impish
2022-02   5.13    20.04.4

2022-04   5.15    22.04    Jammy
2022-08   5.15    20.04.5  Final. No further point releases to 20.04

2025-04                    End of Community Support for 20.04

2030-04                    End of Life for 20.04. End of ESM
```

The 22.04 cycle will follow a similar pattern. Every LTS release for the past decade has followed this pattern.

- Keep in mind that point releases are not *governed* by the schedule -- you cannot predict the exact day (or week) a point release will occur. They release when they are ready, and releases may be delayed a few days if a critical bug is discovered in testing.

Comment: Thanks. Please update your answer when things changed.

Answer (score 5):

It's coming in February 2023. Check out these screenshots which came from this link:
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906

[image]

[image: Here's a snapshot]