# How to install latest ubuntu *signed* kernel on lts

Tags: upgrade, kernel, updates, uefi, lts

[Installing mainline kernels](https://askubuntu.com/q/119080/) is not an option because it is not signed for SecureBoot: I hit *[bad shim signature](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427351/issue-with-booting-kernel-over-5-15-0-47-ubuntu-22-04)* and I cannot disable SecureBoot nor enroll my own signing keys on my system (locked BIOS).

How can I install the latest signed available kernel, at this time [kinetic/linux-generic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/linux-generic) ie around 5.19.0-19, made for 22.10, on 22.04 LTS?

Note that such kernels only end up in ubuntu LTS only ~4 months later ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1424114/220798)).

---

*What i have tried so far:*

```bash
root=http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/
wget \
$root/l/linux-signed/linux-image-5.19.0-19-generic_5.19.0-19.19_amd64.deb \
$root/l/linux/linux-headers-5.19.0-19-generic_5.19.0-19.19_amd64.deb \
$root/l/linux/linux-headers-5.19.0-19_5.19.0-19.19_all.deb \
$root/l/linux/linux-modules-5.19.0-19-generic_5.19.0-19.19_amd64.deb \
$root/l/linux/linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-19-generic_5.19.0-19.19_amd64.deb \
$root/l/linux/linux-modules-iwlwifi-5.19.0-19-generic_5.19.0-19.19_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

kernel does seem to pass the shim signature check, but locks up, 100% CPU, and only prints the unhelpful "standard" buggy DELL bios errors:

*DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid

ACPI error: Thread ... cannot release mutex [ECMX] ...

Aborting method _SB.PC00.LPCB.ECDV._Q66 due to previous error (AE_AML_NOT_OWNER)*

Comment: It is totally unclear why would you need this and why would you need Secure Boot. But you can download a kernel from 22.10 repos and install to 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

It seems either I initially hit an issue with specific version 5.19.0-19, or latest firmware&microcode was needed.

So, the following instructions work:

```bash
root=http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/
major=5.19.0
patch=24
rev=25

wget \
$root/l/linux-signed/linux-image-$major-${patch}-generic_$major-${patch}.${rev}_amd64.deb \
$root/l/linux/linux-headers-$major-${patch}-generic_$major-${patch}.${rev}_amd64.deb \
$root/l/linux/linux-headers-$major-${patch}_$major-${patch}.${rev}_all.deb \
$root/l/linux/linux-modules-$major-${patch}-generic_$major-${patch}.${rev}_amd64.deb \
$root/l/linux/linux-modules-extra-$major-${patch}-generic_$major-${patch}.${rev}_amd64.deb \
$root/l/linux/linux-modules-iwlwifi-$major-${patch}-generic_$major-${patch}.${rev}_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb

# fixes "Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_70.1.1.bin for module i915" etc
wget \
$root/a/amd64-microcode/amd64-microcode_3.20220411.1ubuntu3_amd64.deb \
$root/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_20220923.gitf09bebf3-0ubuntu1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i --auto-deconfigure linux-firmware_*.deb amd64-microcode_*.deb
```

To uninstall

```bash
major=5.19.0
patch=19
sudo apt remove linux-image-$major-${patch}-generic linux-headers-$major-${patch} linux-modules-$major-${patch}
```

*Note*: you will need to edit the major/patch/rev and firmware/microcode version according to what can be found in http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/ - as only the latest build is present.